# C# Accessing member variable from one class to another

Tags: c#

So I'm working with two files: Simulator and Environment. In the environment file, I have a member variable called **"Entities"**. It is defined there and it has constructor and a get-set function. My Simulator class has that Environment class included in its code; with a constructor and a set-get function for it.

Now I am trying to make the Environment class to work within the Simulator class. The code I have right now is supposed to include the environment member variable **"Entities"** in a for loop code I wrote inside my Simulator class.

The error I'm receiving is that the variable member doesn't exist in the current context. However I want to let the computer know that the member variable is from the Environment class. How can I fix this error? I'm using C#.

This is the code I'm having problem with:

**the run() method, from my simulator class**

```
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50 && entities.Count > 1; i++)
        {
            entities.RemoveAll(m => !m.IsAlive());

            step(i);
        }

    }
```

Here is the environment class.

```
#region ENVIRONMENT CLASS
  //__________________//
 //   ENVIRONMENT    //
//__________________//
public abstract class ENVIRONMENT
{
    private List<ENTITY> entities;

    public ENVIRONMENT()
    {
        entities = new List<ENTITY>();
    }

    public void AddEntity(ENTITY e)
    {
        entities = new List<ENTITY>();
        entities.Add(e);
        Random rand = new Random();

        foreach (ENTITY element in entities)
        {
            int locX = rand.Next(0, 9);
            int locY = rand.Next(0, 9);
            element.X = locX;
            element.Y = locY;

            //element.LocalPoint.X = locX;
            //element.LocalPoint.Y = locY;
        }
    }

    public ICollection<ENTITY> Population
    {
        get { return entities; }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Earlier I gave another name for Entities and that was List, so I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a field named LIST, but I do see a field named `entities`, of type `LIST<ENTITY>`.

Add an `internal` or `public` `get` property accessor for your `entities` variable, and initialize `entities` to an empty list upon class instantiation.

Also, why are all of your class names (apparently) fully UPPERCASE?

```
public abstract class ENVIRONMENT
{
    private List<ENTITY> entities = new List<ENTITY>();

    public List<ENTITY> Entities
    {
        get { return entities; }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot. I made the correction earlier, changing "list" to "entities" without editing my post. I'm making my class names uppercase only to organize my files. I have two different projects under one solution, and each one contains one or more files with same name.  

I've tried that approach, but it doesn't seem to make the error go away. It still says the entities doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Could you add a reference to where the problem/error is being raised?